# New-PSDrive inside a module doesn't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a module, which is auto-loaded, where I put my everyday functions and variables.

In the hope that a PSDrive is always here when I start a PowerShell session, at the very beginning of  MyPSModule I call:

```
$script_directory = 'D:\scripts\'
New-PSDrive -Name Scripts -root $script_directory -PSProvider FileSystem
```

However, after I open a new PowerShell environment, and that my module is loaded: `Get-PSDrive` doesn't list my drive. ( I'm sure my module is loaded, I called some of its functions, I even re-imported with `-Force`, and `Import-Module -Verbose` doesn't show any errors )

I have to manually call: `New-PSDrive -Name Scripts -root 'D:\scripts\' -PSProvider FileSystem`.
Only in such a case will `Get-PSDrive` list my drive.

What is wrong ? What should I do so as the PSDrive is created at the loading of my module ?

Comment: not sure about the `Get-PSDrive` behavior but is there any reason you use a module instead of your profile?

Comment: I had similar experience with [`Mount-VHD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848551.aspx) inside a module. The VHD was mounted, but the [`Get-Volume`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848646.aspx) did not see it. I think there is some sort of scoping at play, but I never found any sort of documentation about it. Would like to know the answer myself.

Comment: @Paul thx, it works when put in my profile.ps1 file. However I would like to know the reason this fails as is.

Comment: Try `New-PSDrive ... -Scope Global`. By default variables and objects created in a module are scoped to that module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Parameter `Scope` with value `global`

> -Scope
>
> Specifies a scope for the drive. Valid values are "Global", "Local",
>   or "Script", or a number relative to the current scope (0 through the
>   number of scopes, where 0 is the current scope and 1 is its parent).
>   "Local" is the default. For more information, see about_Scopes
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113260).

```
$script_directory = 'D:\scripts\'
New-PSDrive -Name Scripts -root $script_directory -PSProvider FileSystem  -Scope global
```

Explanation of Scop parameter:

> **Global:**  The scope that is in effect when Windows PowerShell starts.
>   Variables and functions that are present when Windows PowerShell
>   starts have been created in the global scope. This includes automatic
>   variables and preference variables. This also includes the variables,
>   aliases, and functions that are in your Windows PowerShell profiles.
>
> **Local:**   The current scope. The local scope can be the global  scope
>   or any other scope.
>
> **Script:**  The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only the
>   commands in the script run in the script scope. To the commands in a
>   script, the script scope is the local scope.
>
> **Private:** Items in private scope cannot be seen outside of the current
>   scope. You can use private scope to create a private version of an
>   item with the same name in another scope.